# Filling in old 4 foot deep 4 foot wide pond

Tags: pond

We want to fill in a small deep pond, about 4 feet across and 4 feet deep, we want to convert it to a pondless water feature.  the liner is not leaking, want to fill in the most economical way possible without wrecking the liner.  thought of filling with river stones, but then I thought possibly bags of sand unopened would be less expensive  to fill pond halfway or more up, then filling with the small stones to the top.  that way we could fill the pond back up with water and finish with with the pondless water feature.  Does this sound like a good plan? Or is there a more economical way of doing it without endangering the liner.

Comment: River rock is about the most expensive option you could choose. Pebbles (or pea gravel - same thing, different names) will probably only by 1/3 of the price.  I would be cautious about sand bags. They might only stay "unopened" until the local wildlife makes a hole in them!

Answer (score 2):

If it is 4' round X 4 ' deep , that is about 50 cubic ft or about 2 cubic yards or about 4 tons of sand ( 4' square would be bigger).  Check the volume on the bags of rock/sand before you decide. If an independent contractor is digging in the area he may be willing to dump a couple yard of fill on your drive way . Then hire day labor if you don't want to move it yourself. Not that bad; I had 10 yards dumped on my drive and moved it myself (80 years old) a few feet to where I needed it . It did take over a week.